# Scrapy Value Error f'Missing scheme in request

Tags: css, web-scraping, scrapy, href

I'm new in scrapy and I'm trying to scrap https:[opensports](https://www.opensports.com.ar).I need some data from all products, so the idea is to get all brands (if I get all brands I'll get all products). Each url's brand, has a  number of pages (24 articles per page), so I need to define the total number of pages from each brand and then get the links from 1 to Total number of pages.
I ' m facing a (or more!) problem with hrefs...This is the script:

```
 import scrapy
 from scrapy import Request
 from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
 from datetime import datetime
 import datetime

 #start_url: https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html
 class SolodeportesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'solodeportes'
     start_urls = ['https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html']
     custom_settings = {'FEED_URI':'opensports_' + f'{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H%M%S")}.csv', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', }

     #get links of dif. brands 
     def parse(self, response):
         marcas= response.css('#maincontent > div.category-view > div > div.brands-page > table > tbody  td a::attr(href)').getall()
         for marca in marcas:
             yield Request(marca, self.parse_paginator)

     #get total number of pages of the brand And request all pages from 1 to  total number of products
     def parse_paginator(self,response):
         total_products = int(int(response.css('#toolbar-amount > span:nth-child(3)::text').get() / 24) + 1)
         for count in range(1, total_products):
             yield Request(url=f'https://www.opensports.com.ar/{response.url}?p={count}',
                      callback=self.parse_listings)



     #Links list to click to get the articles detail
     def parse_listings(self, response):
         all_listings = response.css('a.product-item-link::attr(class)').getall()
         for url in all_listings:
             yield Request(url, self.detail_page)

     #url--Article-- Needed data
     def detail_page(self, response):
        yield {
        'Nombre_Articulo' :response.css('h1.page-title span::text').get(),
        'Precio_Articulo' : response.css('span.price::text').get(),
        'Sku_Articulo' : response.css('td[data-th="SKU"]::text').get() ,
        'Tipo_Producto': response.css('td[data-th="Disciplina"]::text').get() ,
        'Item_url': response.url
    }


 process = CrawlerProcess()
 process.crawl(SolodeportesSpider)
 process.start()
```

And I'm getting this error message:

> c:/Users/User/Desktop/Personal/DABRA/Scraper_opensports/opensports/opens_sp_copia_solod.py
> 2022-01-16 03:45:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started
> (bot: scrapybot)   2022-01-16 03:45:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO:
> Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12,    cssselect 1.1.0, parsel
> 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.10.1    (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit
> (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography
> 36.0.1, Platform    Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0   2022-01-16 03:45:05 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor:
> twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor   2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:   {}   2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: b362a63ff2281937
> 2022-01-16 03:45:05 [py.warnings] WARNING:
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-
> packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py:247:
> ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The `FEED_URI` and    `FEED_FORMAT` settings
> have been deprecated in favor of the `FEEDS` setting. Please see
> the `FEEDS` setting docs for more details   exporter = cls(crawler)
>
> 2022-01-16 03:45:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
> 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
> 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
> 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2022-01-16
> 03:45:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:       [] 2022-01-16
> 03:45:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at  0 pages/min),
> scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2022-01-16 03:45:05
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6023 2022-01-16 03:45:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html>](https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html%3E) (referer: None)
> 2022-01-16 03:45:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error
> processing <GET [https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html>](https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html%3E) (referer:
> None) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py",
> line 120, in iter_errback
> yield next(it)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py",
> line 353, in **next**
> return next(self.data)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py",
> line 353, in **next**
> return next(self.data)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py",
> line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
> for r in iterable:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py",
> line 29, in process_spider_output
> for x in result:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py",
> line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
> for r in iterable:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py",
> line 342, in 
> return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py",
> line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
> for r in iterable:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py",
> line 40, in 
> return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py",
> line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
> for r in iterable:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in 
> return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py",
> line 56, in *evaluate_iterable
>
> for r in iterable:   File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\opensports\opens_sp_copia_solod.py",
> line 16, in parse
> yield Request(marca, self.parse_paginator)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request_*init**.py",
> line 25, in **init**
> self.*set_url(url)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_opensports\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request_*init**.py",
> line 73, in _set_url
> raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')         ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /marca/adidas.html
> 2022-01-16 03:45:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
> (finished) 2022-01-16 03:45:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping
> Scrapy stats:    {'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
> 'downloader/request_count': 1,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET':
> 1,  'downloader/response_bytes': 22711,  'downloader/response_count':
> 1,  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
> 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.748282,  'finish_reason': 'finished',
> 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 16, 6, 45, 7, 151772),
> 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 116063,
> 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,  'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
> 'log_count/ERROR': 1,  'log_count/INFO': 10,  'log_count/WARNING': 1,
> 'response_received_count': 1,  'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
> 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,  'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
> 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,  'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
> 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 16, 6, 45, 5, 403490)}

At first I have a problem with the f' url...I don't know how to concatenate the url because in :

```
marcas= response.css('#maincontent > div.category-view > div > div.brands-page > table > tbody  td a::attr(href)').getall()
```

I get this type of url (I don't know if it's ok or I need the https:// part):

```
'/marca/adidas.html'
```

I know that it's wrong and I coudln't find a way to fix it...Could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: error is clear enough, the url you are trying to scrape does not have scheme https or http in the beginning ... print url in shell and construct the url with proper scheme ... and error will disappear

Comment: Yes, I understand but I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the relative you can use `response.follow` or with request just add the base url.

Some other errors you have:

1. The pagination doesn't always work.
2. In the function `parse_listings` you have class attribute instead of href.
3. For some reason I'm getting 500 status for some of the urls.

I've fixed errors #1 and #2, you need to figure out  how to fix error #3.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime
import datetime


#start_url: https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html
class SolodeportesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'solodeportes'
    start_urls = ['https://www.opensports.com.ar/marcas.html']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'opensports_' + f'{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H%M%S")}.csv', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    }

    #get links of dif. brands
    def parse(self, response):
        marcas= response.css('#maincontent > div.category-view > div > div.brands-page > table > tbody  td a::attr(href)').getall()
        for marca in marcas:
            yield response.follow(url=marca, callback=self.parse_paginator)

    #get total number of pages of the brand And request all pages from 1 to  total number of products
    def parse_paginator(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_listings, dont_filter=True)
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "next")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_paginator)

    #Links list to click to get the articles detail
    def parse_listings(self, response):
        all_listings = response.css('a.product-item-link::attr(href)').getall()
        for url in all_listings:
            yield Request(url, self.detail_page)

    #url--Article-- Needed data
    def detail_page(self, response):
        yield {
            'Nombre_Articulo': response.css('h1.page-title span::text').get(),
            'Precio_Articulo': response.css('span.price::text').get(),
            'Sku_Articulo': response.css('td[data-th="SKU"]::text').get(),
            'Tipo_Producto': response.css('td[data-th="Disciplina"]::text').get(),
            'Item_url': response.url
        }
```

Comment: ohhhh SuperUser, this is so helpful!!. I really appreciate your help. I didn't notice the mistakes. It's a new world for me, I'll do my best to fix #3. I'll post if get a solution! thank you very much!

Comment: @MaximilianoVazquez No problem. Good luck!